# How To Reinitialize Datatable in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I Need

*When Ajax is loaded datable is reintailized.

- i would explain in steps

  1. Here is the output of first step :http://postimg.org/image/c6p8jwp3b/.
  2. Here is the output of second step :http://postimg.org/image/6fm1z253h/
  3. Here is the output of third step:http://postimg.org/image/5btny60xf/.
- No Reinitialize Of datatable.
- I just want paging and search should be reintialized.
- i have taken help from this url: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/256/fnreloadajax/p1.

Ajax call code:

```
   if ($('#teamTable').size() > 0)
    {

        $('#teamTable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
        });
    }

      $("#save_team").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "asana_team.php",
            data: { people_name: $('#e2').val(), team_name:$('#teamname').val() },
            beforeSend : function(){
                $("#team_table").remove();
                $("#team_table_div").append("<center id=\"loading\" style=\"margin-top:25%;margin-bottom:25%\"><img src='../common/images/ajax-loader.gif' /></center>");
            },
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("#loading").remove();
                $('#team_table_div').append(data);
                $('#teamTable').dataTable({
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
                });                    
            });
        });
```

* working fine  but i reintializing pagination in datatable no datable is loaded.

- i have used this code  to reinitailize table.

  ```
   function callBack()
   {
   var call= $('#teamTable');

  call.dataTable({
   "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
   "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
   "oLanguage": {
   "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
   } });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
  callBack();
  });
  ```

Comment: try in success function

Comment: i have tried  but no solution table is not rintialized

Answer (score 17):

Destroy first using

```
    $('#teamTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Then reinitailize

```
    $('#teamTable').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

First I initalize the datatable, with

```
$(".myTable").DataTable({ "bDestroy": true, .... });
```

The "bDestroy" attribute was necessary in my case.

Then when I have something to append dynamically to my table I do the following:

```
$(".myTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
//Append stuff to my table
$(".myTable").DataTable({ "bDestroy": true, ... });
```

Also notice that I use the `dataTable()` function when destroying the table and the `DataTable()` function when initalizing it.

Answer (score 7):

**This worked for me after a lot of research:-** First check if dataTable exist or not, if it does then destroy dataTable and recreate it

```js
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#mytable")) {
  $('#mytable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}

$("#mytable").dataTable({...
                       
                });
```

Comment: I've tried this. But, I'm getting no data available in the table after this

Comment: @HS_ can you tell, what exactly are you trying to do? because in my case i needed to clear the existing datatable after every database query so that my data didn't keep on adding with existing data so as per this code you destroy the existing datatable (*if exist) and then reinitialize it, which will be empty so you need to do the further processing after this.

Answer (score 6):

This is what helped me.

```
$('#teamTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$('#teamTable').empty();
```

`.empty()` was important as after `.fnDestory()` the table element still had the data lurking around, which also got carried forward to the reinitialized table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#table").dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            // ...
        });
```

Comment: `"destroy": true,` helps to dynamically reinitialize the datatable

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#t_isteklerim")) {
        $("#t_isteklerim").DataTable().clear().draw();
        $("#t_isteklerim").dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#t_isteklerim').empty();
    }


var table = $('#t_isteklerim').DataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        'dom': 'BRlfrtip',
        "columns":        [
            {'id':'id'},
            {'tekliftarihi':'tekliftarihi'},
            {'istektarihi':'istektarihi'},
            {'istekadedi':'istekadedi'}
        ],
        "language":{"url":"<?=base_url()?>assets/libs/misc/datatables/Turkish.json"},
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "autoWidth":      true,
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?=base_url()?>tekliflerim/fx_get_items_isteklerim",
            type : 'GET'
        }
    }  );
```

DataTable() and dataTable() are different!

Answer (score 1):

Taking help from @ravi dudi's answer I modified one line and that solution worked for me after lots of research. In my case clearing data didn't helped so, I am only destroying existing instance and reintialising after ajax.

```
//Check if datatable instance exists before ajax starts:
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#dtid')) {
    $('#dtid').dataTable().fnDestroy();               
}

//reintialise after ajax success:
$('#dtid').DataTable({
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need to store dataTable inside a variable to be able to change options or call functions.

first step :
storing table into variable

```
 var oTable = $('#teamTable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
        });
```

second step : 
inside your ajax request, when you want to clear the table.

```
if (oTable != undefined) {
    oTable.fnClearTable();
}
```

EDIT

```
var oTable; 
if ($('#teamTable').size() > 0)
    {

        var oTable = $('#teamTable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"   //storing the instance of the dataTable for futher use in the future
        });
    }

      $("#save_team").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "asana_team.php",
            data: { people_name: $('#e2').val(), team_name:$('#teamname').val() },
            beforeSend : function(){
                $("#team_table").hide(); //we dont need to remove table, only hide it..
                $("#team_table_div").append("<center id=\"loading\" style=\"margin-top:25%;margin-bottom:25%\"><img src='../common/images/ajax-loader.gif' /></center>");
            },
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("#loading").remove();
                $('#team_table_div').append(data);
                $('#teamTable').show();
                //here we clean the data from the table
               if (oTable != undefined) {
                    oTable.fnClearTable();
               }                  
            });
        });
```

Comment: could  you tell in which code segment i have made changes

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: i dont fully get what you need when i re-reading the question.. you want the new data to be inserted into the table? without destroying the options?

Comment: error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fnSetData' of undefined

Comment: i think because it has no columns defined, am i right?

Comment: i  just want load boostrap search and paging on  rintializing datable

Comment: yes absolutly , and boostrap search and paging is again load when user click on button in second step