# Dropdown list selected value changes during debug but not at runtime

Tags: jquery, datatables

EDIT:

Using datatables, I'm sending two datatables ajax requests when a dropdown list value changes.  When I debug with the F12 tools in Firefox, I'm getting the NEW selected value of the dropdown list at the breakpoint in the dropdown list selected change event, but when I continue, the value of that variable stays at the old value

```
   $('#mylist').on('change', function () {              
            getData($("#mylist:selected").html());
        }); 

   function getData(ag) {
            var Table1 = $('#tb1').DataTable({
                retrieve: true,
                "paging": true,
                "searching": false,
                "dom": '<Bfrtip>',                    
                "ajax": {
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "url": "/myaction",
                    "type": "POST",

                    "data": { myparam: ag,  },
                    "dataSrc": "bla",
                    error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
               {  ....                      
                ],
            });


           ........
```

Comment: What does your html look like? I'm assuming `#mylist` is a `<select>` element, but what is `#mylistoption`? There may be issues with that selector...

Comment: Sorry I edited it.  The selectors are the same,  #mylist is a <select> element

Comment: Can you provide a "working" demo?

Comment: I actually solved it by first destroying the table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452270/how-to-reinitialize-datatable-in-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#mylist').on('change', function () {              
  getData($("#mylist").find(":selected").text());
});
```

Corrected the `:selected` element selector, and changed `.html()` to `.text()`, a little bit safer if you are passing this value to your API.